# Is Wordpress hijacking my Ajax form post?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I'm new to Wordpress and new to JQuery, so let me start off explaining what I am trying to do.

I have an admin page, inside this page I'm giving the user the ability to upload an image. I want this done using Ajax (independent from the general form update).

Here is the code I have so far:

1. At top of page - script includes:

<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js">

I can confirm these scripts are "pingable" and work.

Now the HTML code :

```
<table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="100" style="padding:10px" valign="top">Email Image (180x180):</td>
                    <td style="padding:10px"><img id="previewEmailImage" width=180 height=180>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <div id='emailpreviewloader'>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/ajaximage.php">
                            <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

The key things in the HTML is a) a form and b) The div emailpreviewloader.

Now just after the html table, inline I have the following js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function()
                {
                    $('#photoimg').live('change', function()
                    {
                        $("#emailpreviewloader").html('');
                        $("#emailpreviewloader").html('<img width="180" src="/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');

                        $("#imageform").ajaxForm(function(result)
                            {
                                alert("Thank you for your comment!");
                            });
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

for testing purposes ajaximage.php just contains 1 line: Echo "It worked";

So assuming I've done my job right, and the html + js above is correct, it would seem Wordpress might be hijacking the Ajax somehow and preventing it from working as expected. Is this possible?

All I want to do is have a regular Ajax post, how is this possible?

EDIT:

**What is working:**

The change event for the file upload control is firing. I've confirmed this with an alert, and the loader.gif is visible. But it would seem the form isn't firing, or not firing correctly. The inner alert, never fires.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use wordpress's functions for ajax calls, try sending the form to `action="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/ajaximage.php"` and make sure the file is in the root of your wordpress instalation.